# Relates Human body with Abstract class and interface?

Tags: interface, abstract

This is the question asked me in the interview. I am looking for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a human could be a class, a body could be a class, and an interface could be a class. Humans can interface with humans. Humans can interface with computers. Maybe they were asking if you can relate the human body to a class and an interface; in this case the answer is yes or no.

Comment: Please don't try to answer unclear and off-topic questions. This will only encourage people to send them.

Comment: Good point. Maybe the question is better for the workplace exchange?